Sentry profiling more than one endpoint
I setup sentry with similarl parameters to the tutorial but i initialize the app with lifespan.
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.starlette import StarletteIntegration
from sentry_sdk.integrations.fastapi import FastApiIntegration


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):

   sentry_sdk.init(
    # ...
    integrations=[
        StarletteIntegration(
            transaction_style="endpoint"
        ),
        FastApiIntegration(
            transaction_style="endpoint"
        ),
    ],
)


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan, docs_url="/app/docs")

app.include_router()
app.include_router()

I add multiple routers in my app which define several endpoints. I can see the endpoints in the sentry app, but when in the profiling panel, I can see that the profile of an endpoint contains profiling of code of another endpoint entirely, or of some background tasks added by another endpoint.
Can someone explains why this happens?
